# SQL Developer won't show the connections Tab area

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Can someone help me ? I was try version 19 and 20 but I have same error.

I was try WINDOW - (Reset Windows to factory settings) then same error :/

https://www.linkpicture.com/q/oracle.png

Comment: Double click on connection tab or try to select and drag connection tab.

Comment: What OS and what java are you running?